# The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled - Codeigniter

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter with HMVC framework and wanted to use MongoDB.

1. I installed the application/config/mongo_db.php
2. application/libraries/Mongo_db.php
3. Add mongo_db in autoload library

I also downloaded the relevant dll files and saved them in the extn folder of php.

I also added the extensions in extension=php_mongodb.dll and extension=mongo.so in php.ini

Still i'm getting this message.

I'm using php v 5.6

When I do php info I get the following, which shows that mongodb is installed and seems to be working. However,

```
echo extension_loaded("mongo") ? "loaded\n" : "not loaded\n";
```

shows not loaded.

[image]

Am i missing something?

Comment: improved readibility.

Comment: i checked and still getting the same error